# compiling valgrind using uCLibc

Tags: compilation, valgrind, uclibc

I am working on a project and i want to compile **valgrind** using **uClibc**.
Can anyone suggest me something about how to proceed?

I am using fedora and i386 platform. the target platform is also i386 at the moment later on would work on MIPS.

thanks

Comment: I totally forgot to do that. Now it has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use [toolchain](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/buildroot-2012.02.tar.gz) provided by buildroot. Just install it and cross compile the valgind .

Answer (score 2):

Valgrind does not support the MIPS instruction set, so unless you put some significant effort to port Valgrind on MIPS, it is not possible to use Valgrind on this architecture.

Comment: For future reference... MIPS support was added to Valgrind 3.8.0 (Aug 12 2012). http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29656884